# Regex to match a pattern and exclude list of string

Tags: regex

I am pretty new with Regex.

Basically I am trying to create a regex to assess the URL path from our system. However, there is a known bug in our system which causing the URL path become really messy..

Ideally, the URL should be

```
/mobile/retail.*
```

Due to the bug, the URL will have ‘something else’ in between the ‘/mobile’ and ‘/retail’ something like this

`/mobile(/.*)?/retail`

But the challenging bit is when there is some words that I would like to ignore in that ‘something else’ i.e. sale, search, lot, login. So the case should look like this

So I have a test case like this:

- /mobile/retail -> match
- /mobile/retail/something -> match
- /mobile/something/retail/something -> match
- /mobile/something/retail/something/sale -> match
- /mobile/something/something/retail/something/sale -> match
- /mobil/sale/something -> dont match
- /mobile/something/sale/something -> dont match
- /mobile/something/sale/something/retail -> dont match
- /mobile/lot/test/retail -> dont match
- /mobile/test/lot/test/retail -> dont match
- /mobile/path/test2/test3/testx/lot/test/retail -> dont match

I am kinda stuck with this regex and it is not working as how I want it..

```
/mobile(/(?!sale|search|lot|login).*)?/retail.*
```

The regex above does not work in the condition such:

- /mobile/something/sale/something/retail
- /mobile/test/lot/test/retail
- /mobile/path/test2/test3/testx/lot/test/retail

The word to exclude is strict. For example, the below list should pass:

- /mobile/plot/retail
- /mobile/lots/retail
- /mobile/lots-of-sale/retail
- /mobile/sale-item/retail/something/test/sale
- /mobile/search-prg-item-test/test/retail

Anyone with a strong regex knowledge and any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

First try this:

```
/mobile(?:/(?:(?!sale|search|lot|login)[^/])++)*/retail.*
```

If that fails to compile (you didn't specify your regex flavor), try

```
/mobile(?:/(?:(?!sale|search|lot|login)[^/])+)*/retail.*
```

**Explanation:**

```
/mobile                     # Match "/mobile"
(?:                         # Match...
 /                          # a slash
 (?:                        # followed by...
  (?!sale|search|lot|login) # (only if these strings arent't present
  [^/]                      # any character except slashes
 )++                        # Match at least one and don't backtrack
)*                          # Do this zero or more times
/retail                     # Then match "/retail"
.*                          # plus whatever follows
```

Answer (score 2):

A regex that matches parts between slashes repeatedly, where such a part may not be sale, search, lot, or login:

```
^/mobile(/(?!sale|search|lot|login)[^/]*)*/retail.*
```

Comment: I think this is better than mine because it would let paths like `/mobile/plot/retail` pass (which mine would reject). Of course, yours would also reject `/mobile/lots/retail`. @Wilson didn't quite specify how strictly those "bad words" need to be interpreted.

Comment: Hi Tim, it is only specific to /lot/ or /sale/ so for instance, I am expecting /mobile/plot/retail and /mobile/lots/retail to pass. Another example.. if it is /mobile/saleitem/retail should pass too. If that makes sense

Comment: I found this regex: /mobile(?!(.*)(/sale/|/search/|/lot/|/login/).*/retail).*/retail.* and looks like it is working! :)